# Ayuda con select dinamico

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Hola estoy haciendo un select dinamico con php y mysql encontre un ejemplo pero no estaba en mvc asi que trate de cambiar algunas cosas como la direccion donde esta mi controlador pero se queda en un bucle y no me muestra nada en el select

```
Este es mi modelo
<?php
class Trat
{
    public function selectNombre ()
    {
        try {
            include('../model/conexion.php');
            $rows = null;
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM n_tratamiento");
            $stmt->execute();
            while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
                $rows[] = $result;
            }
            return $rows;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
      public function selectDescripcion ()
    {
        try {

            include('../model/conexion.php');
            $rows = null;
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM d_tratamiento where id_descripcion=$nombre_t");
            $stmt->execute();
            while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
                $rows[] = $result;
            }
            return $rows;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Mi vista

```
</head>

<body class="">
    <div  class="container" >


<h1>ACEPTACION DE TRATAMIENTOS Y PRESUPUESTOS DE PACIENTE</h1>
        <select class="form-control" id="continentes"required="required" name="txtN_tratamiento">
         <option value="">--Seleccione--</option>
                      <?php Select();?>
                    </select>
                     <select class="form-control" id="paises" required="required" name="txtD_tratamiento">
         <option value="">--Seleccione--</option>
                      <?php Select2();?>
                    </select>
```

y mi controlador

```
function Select(){
    $consultas=new Trat();

    $filas=$consultas ->selectNombre();

    foreach($filas as $fila){
        echo "<option value=".$fila['id'].">".$fila['tratamiento']."</option>";

    }
}

function Select2(){

    $consultas=new Trat();
     $nombre_t = $_POST['txtN_tratamiento'];
    $filas=$consultas ->selectDescripcion();

    foreach($filas as $fila){
        echo "<option value=".$fila['id_descripcion'].">".$fila['descripcion']."</option>";

    }
}
```

esta es el javascript que deberia funcionar

```
$(function(){

    // Lista de Continentes
    $.post( '../controller/c_presupuesto.php/' ).done( function(respuesta)
    {
        $( '#continentes' ).html( respuesta );
    });

    // lista de Paises  
    $('#continentes').change(function()
    {
        var el_continente = $(this).val();

        // Lista de Paises
        $.post( 'c_presupuesto.php/select()2', { continente: el_continente} ).done( function( respuesta )
        {
            $( '#paises' ).html( respuesta );
        });
    });

    // Lista de Ciudades
    $( '#paises' ).change( function()
    {
        var pais = $(this).children('option:selected').html();
        alert( 'Lista de Ciudades de ' + pais );
    });

})
```

Comment: ¿Qué función tiene el `select()2` aquí: `$.post( 'c_presupuesto.php/select()2'?...`

Comment: @A.Cedano hola el Select2 es el function de mi controlador para llenar el segundo select lo que pasa es que cuando pongo '../controller/c_presupuesto.php/' el select no funciona y el chrome se lentea porque al parecer se queda buscando

Comment: No creo que eso funcione, en el primer parámetro [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) necesita una URL válida. No entiendo para nada lo que intentas hacer.

Comment: @A.Cedano quiero hacer un select dinamico pero en los ejemplos que encuentro las consultas y la parte del controlador van en un solo archivo por eso pongo esa direccion en el url para que llame al select 2 que esta en el controlador porque en los ejemplos normalmente las consultas de los select estan en archivos separados pero yo tengo las consultas en un solo archivo